# a good book on linear projections

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm searching for a good book on linear algebra where the argument of projections, orthogonal and obliquie, are fully explained.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are pretty well covered in any linear algebra text. What exactly do you feel is lacking in ordinary texts?

Comment: not necessary, by example, obliqe projections are generally avoided, also arguments like the partition of unity, and spectral analysis or projections. Also the ortogonality is generaly defined with respect to the euclidean norm, I'm particulary searching for a perspective of projections under general norms, also semi-definite ones.